# Write a function that takes in a list of integers and returns True if it contains 007 in order - my code is not working

Tags: python

#I am unable to understand why this code is not working. I am sure there can be better ways to do it still why this particular code is not working?

```py
# expected outputs:
# spy_game([1,2,4,0,0,7,5]) --> True
# spy_game([1,0,2,4,0,5,7]) --> True
# spy_game([1,7,2,0,4,5,0]) --> False
def spy_game(nums):
    flag = False
    flag_a = False
    for n in nums:
        if (n==0):
            flag = True
            continue
        if (n==0 and flag is True):
            flag_a = True
            continue
        if (n==7 and flag_a is True):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: All `0` values will go into the first `if` block. Try swapping the first and the second `if` blocks.

Comment: show a sample input , the output and expected output

Comment: samples  
 spy_game([1,2,4,0,0,7,5]) --> True
 spy_game([1,0,2,4,0,5,7]) --> True
 spy_game([1,7,2,0,4,5,0]) --> False

Comment: @kol Thanks for the help, can you please guide me to any post or something on how to create mutually exclusive branches for this?

Comment: I have created a very simple state machine implementation, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to fix your function:

```py
def spy_game(nums):
    flag = False
    flag_a = False
    for n in nums:
        if (n==0 and flag is True):
            flag_a = True
            continue
        elif (n==0):
            flag = True
            continue
        elif (n==7 and flag_a is True):
            return True
        
    return False
```

You always should go from more restricted to less restricted, when you use conditional clause (any programming language really).

For more pythonish version you can do:

```py
def spy_game(arr:list, segment:list = [0,0,7]) -> bool:
    l = len(segment)
    for el in arr:
        if(el == segment[0]):
            segment = segment[1:]
        if(len(segment) == 0):
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering. However, the  first one is giving all False in sample cases and second one is giving true to all sample cases

Comment: @joostblack My bad, I thought "in order" means 0, 0, 7 must follow each other. Upvoting ASAP.

Comment: Please fix the `Flase`

Comment: Should work now! Somehow I cannot fix indents next to `a=0` I will login on my laptop and fix it - oddly mobile version cannot cope with the spacing correctly in this case ...

Comment: fixed all the typos + indents!

Comment: I tested the fix with `[1,0,2,4,0,5,7]` and got `False`

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski in the first code  I tried spy_game([1,0,2,4,0,5,7]) and it is still coming False. How to fix that!

Comment: @AKASH BODHANI - try now

Answer (score 1):

My Simpler Approach..

```py
def spy_game(nums):

    bond = [0,0,7,'x']
    
    for num in nums:
        if num == bond[0]:
            bond.pop(0) 
       
    return len(bond) == 1
```

INPUT

```
spy_game([1,2,4,0,0,7,5])
```

OUTPUT

```
True
```

Background iteration until condition is satisfied.

```
[0, 0, 7, 'x']
[0, 7, 'x']
[0, 7, 'x']
[0, 7, 'x']
[0, 7, 'x']
[7, 'x']
[7, 'x']
[7, 'x']
[7, 'x']
[7, 'x']
['x']

True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def spy_game(nums):
    for index, n in enumerate(nums):
        if n==0:
            for index1,n1 in enumerate(nums[index+1::]):
                if n1 == 0:
                    for index2,n2 in enumerate(nums[index1+1::]):
                        if n2 == 7:
                            return True
                        
                    else:
                        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# State machine:
# state = 0: no zero found yet
# state = 1: first zero found
# state = 2: second zero found
def spy_game_fixed(nums):
    state = 0
    for n in nums:
        if state == 0:
            if n == 0:
                state = 1
        elif state == 1:
            if n == 0:
                state = 2
        elif state == 2:
            if n == 7:
                return True
    return False
```

Tests:

```py
tests = [
        [[], False],
        [[0], False],
        [[1], False],
        [[7], False],
        [[0, 0], False],
        [[0, 1], False],
        [[1, 0], False],
        [[1, 1], False],
        [[0, 7], False],
        [[7, 0], False],
        [[7, 7], False],
        [[0, 0, 7], True],
        [[0, 7, 0], False],
        [[7, 0, 0], False],
        [[1, 0, 0, 7], True],
        [[1, 0, 7, 0], False],
        [[1, 7, 0, 0], False],
        [[0, 0, 7, 1], True],
        [[0, 7, 0, 1], False],
        [[7, 0, 0, 1], False],
        [[0, 1, 0, 7], True],
        [[0, 0, 1, 7], True],
        [[0, 1, 2, 0, 7], True],
        [[0, 1, 0, 2, 7], True],
        [[0, 0, 1, 2, 7], True],
        [[1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 7, 5], True],
        [[1, 0, 2, 4, 0, 5, 7], True],
        [[1, 7, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0], False],
    ]
for test in tests:
    if spy_game_fixed(test[0]) != test[1]:
        print("FAIL:", test[0], "shoud give", test[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following code as your solution:

```
def spy_game(nums):
    a=[]
    for i in nums:
        if i == 0:
            a.append(i)
        if i == 7:
            a.append(i)
    if a ==  [0,0,7]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer]. This question is 8 months old and already has 7 other answers, some of which have nice explanations. How does this improve upon what's already here?

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is:

```
def spy_game(nums):
    phrase = ''.join(str(nums))
    if '007' in phrase:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Explaination:

It first turns the list into a string, then it checks if the string '007' is in the string. It is easier than having a number list

Comment: This is wrong. Joining the numbers of the list [10, 0, 7] gives '1007'.

Comment: Sorry. I will do some more testing. I didn't see the example case when I posted

Comment: @AkashBodhani Will there be a case with [10, 0, 7]? If not, and it is only single digits, my code should work fine

Comment: Yes, but the question was about a "list of integers", not about a "list of digits" or "list of single-digit integers". By the way, `''.join(nums)` will throw a TypeError, you have to convert the numbers to strings first.

Comment: @TheFlyingTechie, Thanks for answering. however, yes that is possible to have such cases :(

Comment: Please test the code you post on SO. `str([1,2,3])` gives `'[1, 2, 3]'`, which is obviously not what you intended...

Comment: @kol I have fixed the type error. And, as I said before, I didn't see the example case. Where does it say list? At first I thought it was just a single number

Comment: @AkashBodani I am at a loss. Try the other answer. I apologize for wasting your time

Comment: In the title: "Write a function that takes in a *list of integers* and returns True if it contains 007 in order - my code is not working"